# how to get up the 'grid floor' options

Tags: scale

Pls help me out with something I am trying to do with a character from Daz studio I've imported into Blender.

In the tutorial the person hits the 'N' button and this comes up (pictured here) http://www.imagebam.com/image/94216c1354935377 I do the same and I get the image in the second pic come up here: http://www.imagebam.com/image/97fe9d1354935425 in the same place because likely its a newer version.

What I'm tryin to do is change the grid floor selection to that in the first pic but cannot seem to find the appropriate screen for it when I hit 'N'. How can I do this please.

Answer (score 3):

You can press the little down arrow for Overlays menu. This is in the up-right corner of your 3D-viewport.

[image: Overlays]